# C2055 error - expected formal parameter list, not a type list

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error:

> C2055 error - expected formal parameter list, not a type list

I know what it means; I read about it on the Internet, yet I don't understand why I keep getting it. The part of my code that triggers the error (the file is called `other_funcs.c`):

```
#include "main_funcs.h"
#include "other_funcs.h"

void addWord(sWord **first) //line #4
{
    sWord *after;
    char *input_string, *part;
    const char seperator[4] = "_#_";

    /.......bla bla.... more code.../
```

`sWord` is a `struct`. The error is:

```
1>d:\cs - exercises\ex5\backup\new folder\other_funcs.c(4): error C2055: expected formal parameter list, not a type list
```

I don't know if this is necessary, but the header file with the the `addWord()` function is called `other_funcs.h`:

```
#ifndef OTHER_FUNCS_H
#define OTHER_FUNCS_H

void addWord(sWord**);
char *inputString();
int badInput(char*);
void removeWord(sWord**);
int checkYear(sWord*, unsigned short);
int my_strlen(char*);
int countDist(char*, char*);
int new_alreadyThere(sWord*, char*)
#endif
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you get a truly weird compiler error, look at the *preceding line*.

In this case (ignoring whitespace and preprocessor directives), it's this, from the header file.

```
int new_alreadyThere(sWord*, char*)
```

You're missing a semicolon at the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semicolon on the last line of the header file.

This confuses the compiler when it tries to parse the next line.